# How to solve the distribution of $x$ in the Langevin equation?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

There is a Langevin equation:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = -a\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \xi(t),
$$
where $\xi(t)$ is a Gaussian white noise. I want to know how to prove that $x$ satisfies a Gaussian distribution without using the Fokker-Planck equation.

Additionally, is there a general method for solving the distribution of a variable in any linear stochastic differential equation?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
&\iff e^{at}\left(x''(t) +ax'(t)  \right)=e^{at}\xi(t)\\
&\iff \left(e^{at}\cdot x'(t)\right)'=e^{at}\xi(t)\\
&\iff e^{at}\cdot x'(t)-x'(0)=\int_0^te^{as}\xi(s)ds\\
&\iff  x'(t)=e^{-at}\left(x'(0)+\int_0^te^{as}\xi(s)ds\right)\\
&\iff x(t) = x(0) +\int_0^t \left(e^{-au}\left(x'(0)+\int_0^ue^{as}\xi(s)ds\right)\right)du \\
&= x(0) +x'(0)\frac{1-e^{-at}}{a}+ \iint_ {u\le s\le u\le t}e^{a(s-u)}\xi(s)dsdu\\
&=x(0) +x'(0)\frac{1-e^{-at}}{a}+ \int_0^t \left(\int_s^te^{a(s-u)}\xi(s)du\right)ds\\
&=x(0) +x'(0)\frac{1-e^{-at}}{a}+ \int_0^t \frac{1-e^{-a(t-s)}}{a}\xi(s)ds\\
\end{align}$$

The general method does not exist. Perhaps you could try to guess a particular solution, denoted by $x_1(t)$, after that, you solve the linear differential equation $x''(t)+ax'(t) = 0$ to get $x_2(t)$. And the solution of the linear stochastic equation will be $x_1(t)+x_2(t)$. However, gussing $x_1(t)$ is not easy in practice.

Comment: Thank you! And how to prove that the integral $$ \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-a(t-s)}}{a} \xi(s) \mathrm{d} s $$ follows Gaussian distribution? The central limit theorem?

Comment: @Heritis I think this integral does not follow the gaussian distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. $x(t) = \text{somthing} + \text{an integral}$. So if $x(t)$ follows a Gaussian distribution, why doesn't the integral? @NN2

Comment: @Heritis How do you know that $x(t)$ follows a gaussian distribution?

Comment: Because this is Langevin equation and $x$ is the coordinate of Brownian particle. @NN2

Comment: @Heritis The velocity $x'(t)$ follows a Gaussian distribution but the coordiate $x(t)$ does not.